# Calling Statistica functions from R?

Tags: r, loops, integration

I just found out that there is a white paper on [integrating R in Statistica](http://www.statsoft.com/solutions/r-language-platform/). I was wondering if the other way around is possible as well?

In my case, I would like to use the non-linear regression module in Statistica, however I need to carry out a loop. this is only possible in Statistica using VisualBasic which I am not able to program. So I would like to programm a loop in R that uses Statistica non linear regression.

Does anybody here has experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any obvious package for calling STATISTICA from R.  You have a few options though.

You can call any other executable using `system`.  So if you can call STATISTICA scripts from the command line (sometimes called a "batch mode"), that's one possiblility.

Are you sure that the R integration in STATISTICA doesn't extend to mixing code in the way that you want?

R has many, many packages devoted to regression.  There is almost certainly a suitable routine available.

Does STATISTICA really not have native `for` loops?

Figuring out how to write a `for` loop in Visual Basic won't take that long.  It's just

```
For i = 1 To n
  'your statements for the regression
Next i
```

Comment: To add to Richie's excellent comment above, both VB and VBA also has the loop while and loop until options if the loop repeats can be controlled by a condition. There are a lot of free resources for VB/VBA code out there.

Comment: many thanks for your answers!  "R has many, many packages devoted to regression" yes, but my problem deals with non-linear regression including piecewise functions. this works out very easy in STATISTICA but I failed to get it running in R. I think the best way will be to try the VB loop. You are right, it will not take too long to understand it.